# Swift 4 - How to save NSAttributedstring in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsattributedstring

In *.xcdatamodeld* file, I made a attribute *content*, and make its type *transformable*. And after creating NSManagedObject Subclass, I found in properties file, the type of *content* is NSObject? .And now I change NSObject as NSAttributedstring? ,and ran it, build success.But when I save data, this time, a lot of error occurred,these errors is about `UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` by breakpoint. I think my way to save NSAttributedstring in core data has more problem. How to do this with transformable type? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest solution for both Obj-c and Swift.

In Core Data you can  add an attribute, For example let's call it `attributedText`. Then define its type as `Transformable`. After you create the .h file then change the data type of `attributedText` from `NSDictionary` to `NSAttributedString`.

Now you can save the `NSAttributedString` in Core Data.

Recall it as like this:

```
myObject.attributedText
```

It will return your `NSAttributedString`.

**For Swift:**
Try to create a column of Transformable type. Then create your `NSManagedObject` `Subclass`, which will in your case be a swift file. Then simply change the type of the column in the file so that you have something like `@NSManaged var name: NSAttributedString`.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: In this question, I just did the swift part in your answer, and in the runtime error occurred,so how to complete objective-c part? How to create .h file and how to change data type? Would you mind teaching me concretely? thanks!